# LabView NXT Programming - Error 1003

Tags: labview, nxt

I'm using the NXT toolkit addon for LabView 2009 and I'm trying to download a program, targetted to the NXT onto the brick. When compiling, it fails with the error.

Error 1003: The VI is not executable. Most likely the VI is broken or one of its subVIs cannot be located. Select **File>>Open** to open the VI and then verify that you are able to run it.
Source:

- Retry the current operation.
- Restart LabVIEW and try again.

Since no source for the error is shown then I'm at a loss.

I'm connecting with bluetooth, although it is showing the connection as working and I've made other programs that have worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The error states that one of the VIs in the project is not executable or cannot be found. Here are a few questions to consider. Are there many VIs or subVIs in your project? I recommend looking at the VI Hierarchy (`View > VI Hierarchy`). Are you compiling from the Project view - do any of the VIs have a warning symbol next to its name?

One of the VIs must be missing. Look at [this post](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Bug-Writing-to-the-same-trace-in-Citadel-from-two-Sources-at-the/m-p/1195641#M515381) on NI forums. It shows an example of a  "missing" VI. A VI goes missing when:

- LabVIEW is looking for it in the wrong directory (or its filepath changed)
- Its filename changed
- As the linked example shows, use of a polymorphic VI rather than the VI itself ([see here](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/websearch/705C2ECA081F3C7986256C0F00559B02?OpenDocument))

Your error could be caused by a VI which is broken:

- An error within the VI prevents it from running (harder to track down)